# htaccess rule to redirect old blog urls to the new url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a Wordpress blog at the following URL:

> www.example.com/Folder1/blog

I want to move it up one folder to:

> www.example.com/blog

After moving all Wordpress files, I want to write a .htaccess rule that will redirect ALL my old links to the new ones automatically, like:

> www.example.com/**Folder1/blog/article-one**
>
> to
>
> www.example.com/**blog/article-one**

I've tried a lot of .htaccess rules, but none of them worked. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside **`/Folder1/.htaccess`** place this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: one question: can I use 301 instead of 302, since the move is permanent? please let me know. until then, I will use the code as it is. thanks.

Comment: Yes 302 is good for testing only, once you verify it is working then change this to 301.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1.*$ http://example.com/folder2/ [R=301,L]
```

[source](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs)

Comment: Hey! This almost works, but it redirects every old URL to the new root, not to the new URLs. For instance:

www.example.com/Folder1/blog/a.txt

redirects to:

www.example.com/blog/, not www.example.com/blog/a.txt